# How to run static code analysis in netbeans on save

Tags: netbeans, static, analysis

I'm working with Netbeans and would like run static code analysis when I save a java file.

I know I can use the "Inspect" function, but this has to be called manually each time which seems quite tortuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward if you are only using **FindBugs** for static analysis:

- Select **Tools > Options > Editor**, then select the **Hints** tab.
- Select **FindBugs** from the **Language** drop list, then check the box labeled **Run FindBugs in Editor**. Note that the tooltip states "*Will automatically run FindBugs on the currently edited file after save*".

  [image: findBugsOnSave]

Notes:

- I am not aware of any other static analysis tools being integrated into NetBeans in this manner. This solution is only good for FindBugs.
- This will only run static analysis for the saved file, and not for the entire project. That may be viewed as good or bad, depending on your requirements.